# How do I inject a Coldbox plugin into every handler?

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox, wirebox

We have some plugins that are used throughout a Coldbox application.

Is there a way to globally inject these without having to manually specify the property for each one?

I've looked through the [Wirebox docs](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/WireBox.cfm), but can't see anything relevant. (Entirely possible I'm overlooking something; it's a long and dense page.)

It would seem like decorating the FrameworkSupertype might be a way to do this, but I can't find any mention of doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure how well SO is monitored by ColdBox devs, so you might consider asking this over at the Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/coldbox

Comment: Don't know if it's helpful for your app, but in mine, all of my handlers extend a Base handler, and to accomplish what you want I'll often inject the plugin in the Base, which makes it available to the rest of the handlers that extend it.

Comment: The group requires logging in and figuring out what subject line prefix to use, so this was easier. :)

Comment: We were thinking extending might work, but not sure if it'll cause issues with super or anything?   I think I've figured out that the "Coldbox way" of doing it would be binding an aspect - looks like I can use an annotation or instanceOf to do it... maybe. Need to check it out a bit more to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll point out that Stack Overflow also requires logging in and typing a subject :)

There are several ways to accomplish this and honestly any way works.

The first would be to simply call getPlugin("myPlugin") everywhere you want to use it since the getPlugin() method is available in every handler, view, and layout.

The second would be to use mixin injection and place the following at the top of every handler and then access the plugin from the variables scope:
property name="myPlugin" inject="coldbox:plugin:myPlugin";

The third would be to have all your handlers extend a base handler like Joel suggested and place the DI property in your base handler.

The fourth, which you mentioned, would be to use an AOP aspect and bind it to the init() method for every CFC in the handlers directory and set the plugin into the variables scope as an "after" advice.

A fifth option, would be to use an interceptor to listen to the afterHandlerCreation announcement, and manually inject the plugin into the oHandler object.

And a sixth possibility would be to use the requestStartHandler or a the preProcess interception point and place a reference to your plugin in the private request collection (prc) which will also be available in the views and layouts.

So lots of options, and honestly that probably isn't even all of them.  Personally, I'd probably use the afterHandlerCreation interceptor, but you should find the one that works best for you and run with it!

Comment: Nah, SO login lasts for six months or something, whereas I don't leave my personal Google account logged in on non-personal machines.

Anyhow, thanks for the confirmation and options. #1/#2 are what we currently do and want to avoid, but I'll look into the rest. Hadn't even considered using prc for this, even though I've basically done that one for something else. :S